# Is the word 'meander' the same as 'wander'?

Tags: word-difference

In a dictionary, I found the word 'meander', which means 'wander'.  I've heard a lot about the phrase including 'wander', but never about meander.  So is it ok to say, "I meandered through the forest."?  Is it the same as 'wandered'?

Comment: While it does strictly mean the same as "wander", "meander" is most often encountered in reference to a river winding across a landscape. Saying that you "meander through a forest" would be interpreted as saying that you wandered through it in a particular way, performing a sort of slow left-right slalom.

Comment: Yep. Even when the dictionary defines it simply as identical in actual meaning, 'meander' carries the connotation of referring to a frequently changing direction, whereas 'wander' could refer to not only a back-and-forth path, but also a fairly straight (or, realistically, slightly curved in one direction) path through the forest, just as long as there's not a preplanned route or destination involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use "meander"; however, it is more specific than "wander". (See IanF1's comment.)

> **meander** *verb*
>
> 1. to proceed by or take a winding or indirect course:
>      *the stream meandered through the valley*
> 2. to wander aimlessly; ramble:
>      *the talk meandered on*

*Source: Dictionary.com*